# Java Cipher.getBlockSize() throws exception

Tags: java, cryptography

I am curious, why does calling `getBlockSize()` from the snippet below causes the program to throw exception? It works correctly if I use `key2`.

This snippet is just a test and security concerns is not the main topic. The main question is: why is calling that seemingly harmless method cause the program to throw exception?

I am specifically using that `jar` for the `RawBytes` keyspec. I have:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

Here is complete code:

```
/*
javac -cp ./bcprov-jdk15on-1.62.jar why.java
java -cp ./bcprov-jdk15on-1.62.jar:. why
*/

import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

class why
{
    static
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        byte[] ciphertext = {};
        byte[] kbytes = new byte[16];
        SecureRandom rrr = new SecureRandom();
        rrr.nextBytes(kbytes);

        SecretKeySpec key1 = new SecretKeySpec(kbytes, "RawBytes");
        SecretKeySpec key2 = new SecretKeySpec(kbytes, "AES");

        try {
            byte[] plaintext = "hello world".getBytes("UTF-8");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

            System.out.println(cipher.getBlockSize()); // <---- ???

            cipher.init(
                Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key1, new IvParameterSpec(new 
                byte[16]));
            ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
             | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException
             | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
             | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Below is complete stack trace from the above code:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm: AES or Rijndael 
required
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt.init(AESCrypt.java:83)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherBlockChaining.init(CipherBlockChaining.java:93)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:591)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:346)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1393)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1326)
```

I was wanting to supply the output of `getBlockSize()` into the `byte[]` of `IvParameterSpec` to do away with the hard-coding of the numerical `16` as it appears in the code above.

The behavior is specific to BouncyCastle provider.

Comment: Simple, you did not call the `init` yet.

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace at the bottom of the the question post? I may have an answer, but I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @kelalaka if i put "AES" instead of "RawBytes" then it works so it is not that simple.

Comment: It will not work because I cannot call `getBlockSize()` within `init`,  my intention is to eliminate the hardcoding of `16`. I am now able to reconcile this anomaly, and provided the root-cause in my answer below.

Comment: You don't call it 'within `init()`'. You call it afterwards.

Comment: @user207421, then it will be a useless call. I needed the retval of `getBlockSize()` to remove the hardcoded `16` in the `IvParameterSpec` specified in `init`.

Comment: I guess the better question now is:  When is the **block size** determined? If the `Cipher::getInstance` determines this value, then the block size is known prior to `init`.

Comment: As you can plainly see from the exception trace you posted, or by simply running your own code, `Cipher.getBlockSize()` does **not** throw an exception.

Comment: The second argument to `SecretKeySpec` is supposed to be the "standard algorithm name for the key", as stated by the documentation. "RawBytes" is not a standard algorithm or really any kind of algorithm at all. The validity checking of the algorithm argument for the `Key` is left entirely up to the specific provider. Oracle/Sun providers require it to be from a published list and to be consistent with the algorithm specified in `Cipher.getInstance()`. The Bouncycastle provider completely ignores it. In my opinion, the Oracle/Sun choice is better.

Comment: @user207421: `getBlockSize()` throws no checked exceptions. For all currently supported block ciphers it returns the correct value before `init()` is called.

Answer (score -2):

As I was sensing some sort of anomaly in the behavior of my posted code above, whereby there seemed to be a `BouncyCastle` versus `Java default` provider mixed-up involved, I read an old book **Beginning Cryptography with Java** and fortunately from its preview page at page 11, it mentioned that in order to target `BouncyCastle` as the intended provider, I have to do it like this:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding","BC");
```

And indeed, this change has reconciled the anomaly.

Comment: Note, the inter-provider behavior are not equal. But at least, the addition of `"BC"` in the API call allows a targeted intent. Otherwise, another entity will decide your intent.

Comment: This is not really a correct answer. It is considered poor practice to specify a particular provider in Java cryptography, **unless** you have a **compelling** reason to do so. This compelling reason should be clearly explained and documented.

Comment: The **compelling** reason for me is that the different providers are not behaving in the same way. You cited this differences in your comment. In the presence of this possible differences, the explicit targeting to a specific provider gives me control. I consciously referenced the BouncyCastle jar, and therefore I have to explicitly make sure it is the provider that is chosen. From the book **Cryptography with Java** by David Hook, page 11 it stated it is best practice to specify the provider name to avoid issues on precedence and incompatibilities. Can you clarify this?

Comment: They're not behaving in the same way to your buggy code. You should remove the bugs in your code and then see what happens. `"RawBytes"` is not an algorithm. That means it's wrong. It should be `"AES"`, so change it to `"AES"` I don't the book you're referring to, but it seems clear that you are taking that quote out of context.